# Optimize multiple "and" statements in mongo aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

Is there a simpler way that would also improve the performance of this mongodb query. I know I am suppose to group the either one or the other but cant find any docs or example to help me out.

```
const facetQuery = { $facet: {
    xCreated: [
      { $match : { $and : [{ queueStatus: 'Created' }, { queueType: 'x' } ]}},
      { $count: "Created" },
    ],
    xApproved: [
      { $match : { $and : [{ queueStatus: 'Approved' }, { queueType: 'x' }]}},
      { $count: "Approved" }
    ],
    xDisapproved: [
      { $match : { $and : [{ queueStatus: 'Disapproved' }, { queueType: 'x' }]}},
      { $count: "Disapproved" }
    ],
    yCreated: [
      { $match : { $and : [{ queueStatus: 'Created' }, { queueType: 'y' }]}},
      { $count: "Created" },
    ],
    yApproved: [
      { $match : { $and : [{ queueStatus: 'Approved' }, { queueType: 'y' }]}},
      { $count: "Approved" }
    ],
    yDisapproved: [
      { $match : { $and : [{ queueStatus: 'Disapproved' }, { queueType: 'y' }]}},
      { $count: "Disapproved" }
    ],
    zCreated: [
      { $match : { $and : [{ queueStatus: 'Created' }, { queueType: 'z' }]}},
      { $count: "Created" },
    ],
    zApproved: [
      { $match : { $and : [{ queueStatus: 'Approved' }, { queueType: 'z' }]}},
      { $count: "Approved" }
    ],
    zDisapproved: [
      { $match : { $and : [{ queueStatus: 'Disapproved' }, { queueType: 'z' }]}},
      { $count: "Disapproved" }
    ],
  }};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh wow, instead of doing all these separate matches and count you can just dynamically `$group` on both `status` and `type` and then construct the object you need from that:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        type: "$queueType",
        status: "$queueStatus"
      },
      ApprovedCount: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [
            {
              $eq: [
                "$queueStatus",
                "Approved"
              ]
            },
            1,
            0
          ]
        }
      },
      CreatedCount: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [
            {
              $eq: [
                "$queueStatus",
                "Created"
              ]
            },
            1,
            0
          ]
        }
      },
      DisapprovedCount: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [
            {
              $eq: [
                "$queueStatus",
                "Disapproved"
              ]
            },
            1,
            0
          ]
        }
      },
      
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: {
          $arrayToObject: [
            [
              {
                k: {
                  $concat: [
                    "$_id.type",
                    "$_id.status"
                  ]
                },
                v: {
                  $switch: {
                    branches: [
                      {
                        case: {
                          $eq: [
                            "$_id.status",
                            "Approved"
                          ]
                        },
                        then: "$ApprovedCount"
                      },
                      {
                        case: {
                          $eq: [
                            "$_id.status",
                            "Created"
                          ]
                        },
                        then: "$CreatedCount"
                      },
                      {
                        case: {
                          $eq: [
                            "$_id.status",
                            "Disapproved"
                          ]
                        },
                        then: "$DisapprovedCount"
                      },
                      
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xvpwHwlQAFJ)

Comment: Where do you do any matching against queryType (x, y, z) ? and thank you so much for helping this is my first question on StackOverflow

Comment: If you run the code you'll see, the `group` stage takes care of that for you as it groups on both status and type creating all needed permutations.

Comment: Thank you Tom, I am still pretty new to no-sql but love it!